# Rails - map form values to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

How can I set up my Model so fields `project_score`, `employee_score`, and `company_score` all map their values to the database? This is what I mean:

'Low' maps to       1
'High' maps to      2
'Very High' maps to 3
'Urgent' maps to    4

Is there a way to get the textual output in my views, and separately convert that text back into the numbers before saving? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is as follows

```
<%= form_for @something do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :project_score, [["Low", 1], ["High", 2], ["Very High", 3], ["Urgent", 4]] %>
  <%= f.select :employee_score, [["Low", 1], ["High", 2], ["Very High", 3], ["Urgent", 4]] %>
  <%= f.select :company_score, [["Low", 1], ["High", 2], ["Very High", 3], ["Urgent", 4]] %>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, if you had your `Score`s in a database table with an `id` and `name` column.

```
<%= form_for @something do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :project_score_id, Score.all.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]} %>
<% end %>
```

Where you would create an association to the score

`belongs_to :project_score, :class_name => 'Score'`

rather than use the integer. This would also mean you change your fields to `project_score_id, employee_score_id, company_score_id`

You could also create a custom `FormBuilder` that would create some form of `score_select` to make it easier down the road: http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/form-builders-in-rails.html.

When displaying, you'll also need some form of helper method to display the appropriate one:

```
module ScoreHelper
  def score_display(score)
    case score
      when 1
        "Low"
      when 2
        "High"
      when 3
        "Very High"
      when 4
        "Urgent"
    end
  end
end

# in your view
<%= score_display(@something.project_score) %>
```

Or if you have took the `Score` table and `belongs_to` association approach

`<%= @something.project_score.name %>`

Answer (score 0):

You can set-up you model to return something like this:

```
RATINGS = [
  ["Low", 1],
  ["High", 2],
  ["Very High", 3],
  ["Urgent", 4]
]
```

Then `<%= obj.select Model::FREQUENCY.each { |w| w } %>` in the View.